# MFC-related crash when calling constructors

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm currently writing an application using MFC and CLR in visual studio, and my program is crashing whenever I call the constructor of a class I've written (the class is to control a camera over USB).

I've got a base class `CameraBase`:

```
class CameraBase
{
public:
    virtual bool getFrame(cv::Mat& outImage) { return true; };
};
```

and a derived class `LumeneraCamera` (for the specific camera):

```
class LumeneraCamera : public CameraBase
{
public:

    DLL_API LumeneraCamera();

    DLL_API bool connect(int cameraNum);
    DLL_API bool disconnect();
    DLL_API bool getFrame(cv::Mat& outImage);

private:
    //Bunch of misc variables
};
```

These classes are compiled into a DLL and accessed from another program:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Initing camera" << endl;
    camera = new LumeneraCamera();
    //More operations
}
```

When I run the program, it prints `Initing camera` and then fails because of an assertion in dllinit.cpp (line 133: `VERIFY(AfxInitExtensionModule(controlDLL, hInstance));`). It crashes before executing anything in the constructor. I'm not really sure what the problem is but it seems tied to MFC, so I'm currently looking into untangling my project from MFC entirely. Any suggestions or fixes are appreciated!

Comment: Is that not supposed to work? I've got it set to use MFC in a shared DLL with /clr, and it compiles.

Comment: so you create a clr project, then set it to use MFC as a shared DLL?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. It's been a couple days of irritating compiler/linker errors, and I think I did it to fix some problem I was having. I'm trying to replicate the project from scratch and copy/paste my code over (without ever using MFC) but I'm back to the same linker errors (and struggling to remember what I did to fix them).

Comment: This might be related: [Using and Writing DLLs with MFC](http://cygnus.redirectme.net/ProMFC_5/ch12_6.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved it by disabling MFC - a library I was using suggested MFC but as far as I can tell works fine without it.

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN, if your DLL is dynamically linked against the MFC DLLs, each function exported from this DLL which call into MFC must have the AFX_MANAGE_STATE macro added at the very beginning of the function:

```
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
```